# Semantics of INSERT SELECT FOR UPDATE ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, common-table-expression

We have encountered a very peculiar issue with our production system. Unfortunately despite a lot of effort, I have not been able to reproduce the issue locally, so I cannot provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Also, as this is production code, I have had to change the names of the tables in the following example. However I believe I am presenting all the relevant facts.

We have four tables `bucket_holder`, `bucket`, `item` and `bucket_total` created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE bucket_holder (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  bucket_holder_uid UUID NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bucket ( 
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  bucket_uid UUID NOT NULL, 
  bucket_holder_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES bucket_holder (id), 
  default_bucket BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE item ( 
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  item_uid UUID NOT NULL, 
  bucket_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES bucket (id), 
  amount NUMERIC NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE bucket_total ( 
  bucket_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES bucket (id), 
  amount NUMERIC NOT NULL 
);
```

There are also indexes on appropriate columns as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx1 ON bucket_holder (bucket_holder_uid);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx2 ON bucket (bucket_uid);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx3 ON item (item_uid);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx4 ON bucket_total (bucket_id);
```

The idea is that a `bucket_holder` holds `bucket`s, one of which is a `default_bucket`, `bucket`s hold `item`s and each `bucket` has a unique `bucket_total` record containing the sum of the amounts of all the `item`s.

We are trying to do bulk inserts into the `item` table as follows:

```
WITH
unnested AS ( 
  SELECT * 
  FROM UNNEST(
    ARRAY['00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000001a', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000002a']::UUID[], 
    ARRAY['00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000001c', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000002c']::UUID[], 
    ARRAY[1.11, 2.22]::NUMERIC[]
  ) 
  AS T(bucket_holder_uid, item_uid, amount) 
), 
inserted_item AS ( 
  INSERT INTO item (bucket_id, item_uid, amount) 
  SELECT bucket.id, unnested.item_uid, unnested.amount 
  FROM unnested 
  JOIN bucket_holder ON unnested.bucket_holder_uid = bucket_holder.bucket_holder_uid 
  JOIN bucket ON bucket.bucket_holder_id = bucket_holder.id 
  JOIN bucket_total ON bucket_total.bucket_id = bucket.id 
  WHERE bucket.default_bucket 
  FOR UPDATE OF bucket_total 
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING 
  RETURNING bucket_id, amount 
), 
total_for_bucket AS ( 
  SELECT bucket_id, SUM(amount) AS total 
  FROM inserted_item 
  GROUP BY bucket_id 
) 
UPDATE bucket_total 
SET amount = amount + total_for_bucket.total 
FROM total_for_bucket 
WHERE bucket_total.bucket_id = total_for_bucket.bucket_id
```

In reality the arrays passed in are dynamic and have length up to 1000, but all 3 arrays have the same length. The arrays are always sorted so that the `bucket_holder_uids` are in order in order to ensure that deadlock cannot occur. The point of the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` is that we should be able to handle the situation where some of the `item`s were already present (the conflict is on `item_uid`). In this case the `bucket_total` should of course not be updated.

This query assumes that appropriate `bucket_holder`, `bucket` and `bucket_total` records already exist. It is ok for the query to fail otherwise as in practice this situation will not occur. Here is an example of setting up some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO bucket_holder (bucket_holder_uid) VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000001a');
INSERT INTO bucket (bucket_uid, bucket_holder_id, default_bucket) VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000001b', (SELECT id FROM bucket_holder WHERE bucket_holder_uid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000001a'), TRUE);
INSERT INTO bucket_total (bucket_id, amount) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM bucket WHERE bucket_uid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000001b'), 0);

INSERT INTO bucket_holder (bucket_holder_uid) VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000002a');
INSERT INTO bucket (bucket_uid, bucket_holder_id, default_bucket) VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000002b', (SELECT id FROM bucket_holder WHERE bucket_holder_uid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000002a'), TRUE);
INSERT INTO bucket_total (bucket_id, amount) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM bucket WHERE bucket_uid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000002b'), 0);
```

This query appears to have done the correct thing for hundreds of thousands of `item`s, but for a handful of `item`s, the `bucket_total` has been updated by twice the amount of the `item`. I don't know if it's been updated twice or if it was updated once by twice the amount of the `item`. However in these cases, only one `item` has been inserted (inserting twice would be impossible anyway as there is a uniqueness constraint on `item_uid`). Our logs suggest that for the affected `bucket`s, two threads were executing the query simultaneously.

Can anyone see and explain any issue with this query and indicate how it could be rewritten?

We are using version PG9.6.6

**UPDATE**

We've spoken to a core postgres developer about this, who apparently doesn't see a concurrency issue here. We're now investigating really nasty possibilities such as index corruption, or the (remote) chance of a pg bug.

Comment: can you provide some sample data for all tables (so those joins will return some rows)?

Comment: Also, is it a requirement to use WITH clause, not just set of crud statements?

Comment: @MikeTwc I will add some sample data - give me a couple of hours as I'm not with my laptop right now. No requirement to use WITH clause. The requirements are 1) it should be a single statement, 2) if the query returns successfully it means that all of the items passed in are guaranteed to be in the database (either because they were already there or because they were just added).

Comment: I'm happy for the query to fail if one or more of the items cannot be inserted because there is no bucket holder or default bucket - in practice this situation shouldn't occur.

Comment: @MikeTwc Thank you for your answer. I've added some code to insert some sample data as promised. Sorry it didn't come in time for you to write your answer.

Comment: I agree with the core developer you asked. One way to check for corruption would be to `pg_dump` the database and restore it elsewhere. That would catch data inconsistencies.

Comment: I tested your queries on 9.6, don't see any issue. I guess query is OK, more likely some problems with tables/indexes as you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts while waiting for more data

Based on the problem you have, sounds like either inserted_items CTE 
is returning dups or the update  statement somehow got executed twice.
Both sounds weird, probably pg bug? Maybe try to simplify query as much as possible

some ideas:
Looks like you put items to some default bucket first. It doesn't make 
much sense to have join to bucket table in this case (1 to many join). 
Why not just have default bucket id in holder table (or have separate cte for that)

that line doesn't seem to do anything:
  JOIN bucket_total ON bucket_total.bucket_id = bucket.id

Probably it would be sufficient just to insert data into item table.
Why not have bucket_total as a view (like select bucket_id, sum(amount) ... from items ...)
If it takes a while to populate maybe have it as a materialized view or reporting table.
Or if you run that script many times during the day,
probably create a trigger on item table to add/subtract 1 to bucket on insert/delete

assuming that you can reduce your query to something like this:

```
WITH
unnested AS (....), 

  INSERT INTO item (bucket_id, item_uid, amount) 
  SELECT bucket_holder2.dflt_bucket_id, unnested.item_uid, unnested.amount 
  FROM unnested 
  JOIN bucket_holder2 ON unnested.bucket_holder_uid = bucket_holder2.bucket_holder_uid 
   ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

**update**
Tried to run those queries on 9.6 and it worked fine. So I'd think there is no issue with query and pg, probably it's time to recreate table/database. 
Another idea for testing - you can try to change "UPDATE" to "INSERT" for bucket_total update, removing current unique key and creating incremental primary key. This way you can catch/repair double insertions (if that's the case)